# Create table from SqlAlchemy mapping to Class

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Now, I Create a table in MySql throung Python ORM 'SqlAlchemy'

models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, DateTime, MetaData,ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from database import Base

metadata = MetaData()


class test(Base):    __abstract__ = True
    _tablename_ = 'aa_test'
    id = Column(String)
    id2 = Column(String)

def __init__(self, id, id2):
    self.id = self.id
    self.id2 = id2

def __repr__(self):
    return "<test('%d', '%s'>" % (self.id, self.id2)
```

database.py

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    from ConnectingValue import password, id, host, db

    re_str = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://' + id + ':' + \
        password + '@' + host + '/' + db + ''
    engine = create_engine(
        re_str)
    db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(
        autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))

    Base = declarative_base()
    Base.query = db_session.query_property()
    conn = engine.connect()


    def init_db():
        import models  
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

and last testFile1.py

```
from database import init_db, db_session
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper
from database import conn

def main():
create_entry()

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()


def create_entry():
init_db()
```

i want to know the create the table though "Class test"
i made the class... but, I have not been able to function.

Comment: Your testFile1.py file has wrong identation lines, which will cause the program to fail.

Comment: Have you finally make it work? I am trying the same configuration as you do, can you edit your question and output your error message please?

Comment: i can change  locations
 
def create_entry():
init_db()
if __name__ == "__main__":
main()